# Capture automated download webBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, download, browser

I'm making a tool to automate some things at work, we need an aspx webpage where we fill in some information. Then we click on the submit button, which launches a javascript download dialog to download an xml file. I would like to capture the download url so I can open the xml with my application to extract the important information. I'm using a WebBrowser event. Because this is a javascript call the Navigating event, the Navigated event and the DocumentCompleted event dont occur, only the FileDownload event occurs but the url stays the same like the main aspx page.

Does anybody know how I can catch the URL of the download and cancel the download dialog?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution for this but it the webservice I was talking about does now have an API... Problem solved for me.